# Making $-\log(2-4x)\log(x-5)+\log(2x-1)=\log(3-4x)$ into a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, quadratics

How we can work with below equation to get  **quadratic equation**?

> $$-\log(2-4x)\log(x-5)+\log(2x-1)=\log(3-4x)$$

**No need to get the variable x**

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typing your question with MathJax.  Also, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3958690/edit) your question to include your own thoughts/attempts on this problem.

Comment: In pre-calculus you are unlikely to be finding logarithms of negative numbers, yet either $2-4x$ is negative or $2x-1$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

we know that $\log x$ is defined for $x>0$ so

$\log(2-4x) \Rightarrow 2-4x>0 ,\  \frac{1}{2}>x$

$\log(2x-1) \Rightarrow 2x-1 >0 ,\ x> \frac{1}{2}$

that is a contradiction which means there is not a solution